# Lebesgue- and Counting-measure double integral

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be the lebesgue measure and counting measure, respectfully on $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$. Show that it holds that for $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | y=x\}$

$$\int \int 1_A(x,y)d\lambda (x) d\mu(y) =0$$$$\int \int 1_A(x,y)d\mu(y) d\lambda (x)  =\infty$$

to further conclude that $\mu$ can't be $\Sigma$-finite

---

I know that if we have two $\Sigma$-finite measure spaces  then their product measure is unique. Fubini then tells us that if the function $f$ is integrable over the product measure then we can interchange the the order of integration. This  is not the case.

I realize that the point is in that the counting measure: The counting measure does exactly what it says: it counts the number of elements in a set. So any infinite set has counting measure $∞$, while the measure of any finite set is its cardinality. $A$ would have measure $\infty$ wrt. the counting measure. The counting measure is just summation. The  Lebesgue integral of the indicator would just be the Lebesgue measure of $A$.

How do I *actually* show that the double integrals hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for each $y\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\int 1_A(x,y)\,d\lambda(x)=\int 1_{\{y\}}(x)\,d\lambda(x)=0.
$$
On the other hand, for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\int 1_A(x,y)\,d\mu(y)=\int 1_{\{x\}}(y)\,d\mu(y)=1.
$$

Comment: @mathmat $\int 0 \,d\mu=0$ and $\int 1 \,d\lambda=\infty$.

Comment: For a fixed $x$ ($y$, resp.), when does $1_A(x,y)$ equal $0$?

Comment: That's right, $\lambda(\{y\})=0$ and $\mu(\{x\})=1$ and so $\int 1\, d\lambda =\infty$ $\int 0 \,d\mu=0$.

Comment: @mathmat https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/sections-of-sets-and-functions/

Comment: For a given $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $1_A(x,y)=1$ iff $1\{x=y\}=1_{\{y\}}(x)=1$

Comment: @mathmat That's correct.

Comment: It's like $1_B(x)$ (a function of $x$) with $B=\{y\}$.

Comment: Th indicator in my previous comment is a function of $x$ ($y$ is fixed).

Comment: The integral $\int 1\, d\lambda=\lambda(\mathbb{R})=\infty$.